# Sharepoint 2010 MySites url token back to main site

Tags: 2010, my-site

So here is the scenario I have two SP2010 applications http://intranet.mycompany.org and http://my.mycompany.org.

I need to have a link in mysites that will take users back to http://intranet.mycompany.org. I realize I can do this as a static link in navigation but i'd like it to be dynamic as we have a test and production environment.

My question is there a token similair to ~sitecollection or ~site, that I can use within mysites that will give me the url back to the main application url? Also does anyone know of an authoritative list of all available SP replacement tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ~sitecollection and ~site work because SharePoint knows what they are; there's no way for SharePoint to know what web application is your "main application". The other issue is that relative links don't work as well against a different web application. You can put a link in to "/", which will go to the root of the current web application, but the only way to redirect to another web application would be to use an absolute URL.

One option you could use would be to configure a portal site connection on the MySites that points back to the root site on the intranet web app.

You could also store a URL in the property bag and use a custom control to create a link that goes back to that URL, but there's no OOTB replacement token that I'm aware of that'll do what you're looking for.